# Can't get the module quick edit to work (have some error screenshots)

Tags: nodes, entities

I've successfully installed the module Quick Edit that let's you edit nodes in-place (in a similar way to Panels in-place editor) and might save time.

After installing the module I've yet to see any **quick edit button** (img1) So I tried to check permissions and they were seem fine, and I'm the admin (img2). Than I tried to clear cache and again there was no such button, so I went to ran **cron** and some errors appeared (img3+4).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [quick edit drupal page](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickedit) it says,

> Works with any Drupal 7 site (requires the Entity API, CTools and
>   Libraries API (>=2) modules, plus the **Underscore.js** (>=1.5) and
>   **Backbone.js** (>=1.0) JavaScript libraries). If in-place WYSIWYG editing
>   is desired, you must also use the CKEditor module.

You need to download and install the [libraries module](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries)

Then you need to create a libraries folder in `sites/all` folder. So it looks like this `sites/all/libraries`

Then you need to download the [Backbone.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jashkenas/backbone/master/backbone-min.js) and [Underscore.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jashkenas/underscore/master/underscore-min.js) and put them inside the `sites/all/libraries` folder.

I also see you have some other errors, which is not Quick Edit related. Must be from some other module you installed.

What the errors are saying is that you need to create a custom CK editor http://ckeditor.com/builder and make sure you include the **Shared Space** and **Source Dialog** plugins. So under avalable plugins (right column), scroll and find these plugins and click on the left arrow to include them on your CK editor build. Then scroll all the way down, checkmark the I agree to terms box and click on Download. Then you need unzip and put the ckeditor folder in your `sites/all/modules/ckeditor/` folder. So it will look like this `sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor`

Answer (score 1):

Install the the Backbone library.

If you have not installed the [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module, do so first.

Then in your libraries folder (e.g. `sites/all/libraries/`) install the [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) Javascript library and the [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) Javascript library.

Comment: Thank you guys. My aim is to use Quick edit without CKeditor... A minimalist use just to fix some typo's here and there. I must ask, what are Backbone.js and Underscore --- or the better question would be (with hope for the simplest answer possible) why are they needed for the module to work?

Comment: I didn't realize it could be used without CKEditor but it makes sense that it would be. Backbone and Underscore are javascript libraries that need to be installed into the libraries folder, after the libraries module is installed.